# Retrieving a list using ajax and a php page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to pass two variables from a page consisting of two drop down lists do some calculations and retrieve a third list into a div. How can I get this to work.? 
Here's my code.

```
 <HTML>
     <HEAD>

       <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#day").change(function(){

                      var day=$("#day").val();
                      var doctor=$("#doctor").val();

                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"time.php",
                          data:"day="+day+"&doctor="+doctor,
                          success:function(data){
                             $("#testing").html(data);
                          }

                      });

                });
           });
       </script>
      </HEAD>

<BODY>
    <FORM action="post">

   <SELECT id="doctor">//some options</SELECT>      
   <SELECT id="day">//some option </select>


     <div id="testing">
   BLA BLA BLA


      </div>

    </BODY>



 </HTML>
```

On time.php page I do some calculations to retrieve column names with bit value '1' and store result into a drop downlist

```
         <?
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","clinic","myclinic","myclinic");
    // Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $doctor = $_POST['doctor'];

    $day = $_POST['day'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE doctor='" .$doctor."'AND day='"    .$day. "'";
            //Some calculations and store the result into a list


    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if(!$result) 
    {
        echo "Failed to execute the query";
    }

    echo" 
    <table><tr><td>&nbsp;Time&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;<select name='time'>";
    $i = 0;                                 //Initialize the variable which passes over the array key values

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    //Fetches an associative array of the row
    $index = array_keys($row);             // Fetches an array of keys for the row.

    while($row[$index[$i]] != NULL)
    {

        if($row[$index[$i]] == 1) {             
            echo $index[$i];
            echo "<option value='"  . $index[$i]."'>" . $index[$i] . "</option>";
        }
        $i++;
    }       

    echo "</select>";

      ?>
```

Comment: you do not say what is not working

Comment: Apologies :). I want to select a value from day list, so that corrosponding value of doctor and day go into the time.php script some data from a database is retrieved and placed inside a list and this list 'time' shows up in the div on the home page.

Comment: Your php is vulnerable to mysql injections

Comment: again that is just saying what you want to achieve and not what is wrong, ie when trying to use this code what does not happen, or what happens that shouldnt happen? By the look of the code you show it looks like it should work as you want,

Comment: It says undefined index:doctor
        undefined index:day in time.php

Comment: because you use `$_POST` when your data will be in `$_GET`, unless you specify `type:"post"` in your ajax options then data is sent as `GET` variables

Comment: Please include the code that shows how you build your "list" and the statements that construct the http response from the php script eg. `echo mylist;` If you are able to check your http requests and responses in a developer tool that would be handy

Comment: I think request to time.php is not going through. Httpfox's  output does not show a post request to time.php

Answer (score 0):

On the home page where you have the three drop down lists, you should have a js code that takes in the values of the first two list and send a query to the php server with those values.

The php script on the server should output the results into XML file, that is where AJAX name came from.

Then the js on the home page should retrieve the xml file, parse it and populate the results into the third list.

No post/get during this process !!

here is an example

```
function updatehours()
{
  document.getElementById('minute').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('hour').disabled=false;
  // update xml at server side.
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/javascript' );
  script.setAttribute( 'src', 'updatehours.php?file=92007bb48c.xml&date='+document.getElementById('datepicker').value);
  script.deleteFromDocument;
  head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
  setTimeout('processhours()',500);
  setTimeout('processminutes()',1000);
}
function processhours()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  var txt,xx,x,i;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      txt="";
      x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("H");
      for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
        try
        {
          txt=txt + "<option value=\"" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "\">" + x[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</option>";
        }
        catch (er)
        {
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML=txt;
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","hours/92007bb48c.xml",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Note that the updatehours.php is the script in the server that calculates and put the results in the xml file.

Comment: he is using jquery, no need use xhr directly as he is using the jquery ajax method, he also does not need to put the response in xml, he can just output html and add it to the dom directly, no need to do parsing or anything. Also you mention _"No post/get during this process !!"_ but all xhr requests are either get or post for example you are doing a GET

Answer (score 0):

Damn I should have tried that before. I think the source I downloaded didn't support ajax. 
Changed the source to 
             http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

and It worked!

Thank you guys anyway for the input :)